# "chrome.window.onRemoved.addListener()" does not executes when webdriver.quit() is executed in Selenium with Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver, chrome

I want to perform logic on `chrome.window.onRemoved.addListener(),` it works exactly in chrome browser development environment and in selenium when performed with browser UI of selenium test, but when I execute `driver.quit();` in python shell the `onRemoved` event is not performed.

How can I trigger chrome browsers `window.onRemoved/`(any event before window close to get handled in the extension) event in selenium test while applying `Webdrive.quit();`?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/34152390/6793637

```
chrome.window.onRemoved.addListener(), works only when a chrome process is running. The `driver.quit()` closes all the  chrome processes.
```

Use `driver.close()`

or

Could you try this :

```
// Initializing instance of Firefox WebDriver
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);

// Initializing EventFiringWebDriver using Firefox WebDriver instance
    e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);


//create object of EventListerHandler to registeritwithEventFiringWebDriver
        eventListener = new WebEventListener();

        e_driver.register(eventListener);

        e_driver.manage().window().maximize();
        e_driver.get(appURL);
        e_driver.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `driver.close()`?

Quit() kills the browser, which probably does not give it the chance the trigger the events. Close() closes the active window but the browser stays open, although if it is the last window it might quit aswell, maybe you need to open an extra window first.

Comment: yes, on using driver.close() it quits browser as it is only the window. Also I tried to use key commands ALT + F4 but it is also not working.

Comment: After brainstorming on this so much I concluded that there at in this case derivr.quit() is not real implementation of closing chrome browser like real browser, and it must be improved.

Comment: thanks for taking look @Neils van